# XML recursive search and get value of specific key in attribute

Tags: python, xml-parsing

This is my XML file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
      <edmx:Reference Uri="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/csd01/complete/vocabularies/Org.OData.Measures.V1.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Org.OData.Measures.V1" Alias="Measures"/>
      </edmx:Reference>
      <edmx:Reference Uri="http://redfish.dmtf.org/schemas/v1/RedfishExtensions_v1.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="RedfishExtensions.v1_0_0" Alias="Redfish"/>
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Validation.v1_0_0" Alias="Validation"/>
      </edmx:Reference>
      <edmx:Reference Uri="http://redfish.dmtf.org/schemas/v1/Resource_v1.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource"/>
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_0_0"/>
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Resource.v1_1_0"/>
      </edmx:Reference>
      <edmx:Reference Uri="http://redfish.dmtf.org/schemas/v1/Thermal_v1.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Thermal"/>
      </edmx:Reference>
      <edmx:Reference Uri="http://redfish.dmtf.org/schemas/v1/Power_v1.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Power"/>
      </edmx:Reference>
    </edmx:Edmx>
```

I want to get value of `Uri` in `edmx:Reference` attribute using recursive search of XML. 
My question is how to get values of all `Uri` keys in `edmx:Reference` attributes of XML file?'

Comment: Did you try `findall`?

Comment: Yes I have tried

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html? or other xml-related posts on SO?

Comment: The error says, you don't have a valid XML-file. Try to fix this.

Comment: But I have given the same xml that I have shown in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get your uris like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


tree = ET.parse('Chassis_v1.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root.findall('{http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx}Reference'):
    if 'Uri' in item.attrib:
        print (item.attrib['Uri'])
```

Comment: I want to update the values of Uri as well. Can you please explain how to do this?

Comment: The values in xml file are not changing.

Comment: @kishore you can write back your file after you change the xml object

Comment: But I don't want to create a new file after modifications. I want modifications to be done in my current file dynamically

Comment: em...I don't know how to do it dynamically @kishore

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using regex.. If you wanted to use it: (just thought I might aswell include my answer)

```
import re

with open("example.xml") as xml_file:
    xml_data = xml_file.readlines()

    for line in xml_data:
            check = re.findall('<edmx:Reference Uri="(.*)">', line)
            if len(check) != 0:
                print(check[0])
```